# error in $this->upload->do_upload(),

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, ftp

I want to pass text input and 2 files form view->controller->model and when i run this code it's alway error with "You did not select a file to upload."

**View** - on this view i get input of text and two inputs of load files named "myFile" and "myDoc"

```
              <form action="<?=site_url('blog_maintain/save')?>" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><li class="field" style="display:inline"><p><i class = "icon-docs"></i>&nbsp;หัวข้อ : 
              <input class="text input" type="text" placeholder="Topic Input" name = "topic" id ="topic" required="required">
              </p></li>
              <li class="field" style="display:inline"><p><i class = "icon-menu"></i>&nbsp;คำอธิบาย : 
              <input class="text input" type="text" placeholder="Short Description" name = "desc" id = "desc" required="required">
              </p></li>
              <li class="field" style="display:inline"><p><i class = "icon-picture"></i>&nbsp;รูปภาพ :
              ******<input type="file" name = "myFile" id = "myFile" required="required" accept="image/*">******
              </p></li>
              <li class="field" style="display:inline"><p><i class = "icon-attach"></i>&nbsp;ไฟล์แนบ : 
              ***<input type="file" name = "myDoc" id = "myDoc" accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf,.txt,.xls,.xlsx,.ppt,.pptx">***
              </p></li>               
              <li class="field" style="display:inline"><p><i class = "icon-doc-text"></i>บทความ : 
              <textarea class="input textarea" placeholder="Description" rows="5" name = "text" id = "text" required="required"></textarea>
              </p></li>
              <input class="medium btn pill-left default push_seven two columns" type="submit" value = "upload" onclick = "return check();">
              <input class="medium btn pill-right default two columns" type="Reset" value = "Reset">
```

**Model** - in this model i pass the $_POST to controller save_blog()

```
public function save(){
    $this->load->model('blog_maintain_helper');
    $data['result'] = $this->blog_maintain_helper->save_blog();
    $this->loadView('blogMaintainView',$data);
}
```

Controller

```
function save_blog(){           
    $config =  array(
        'upload_path'     => 'server_path',
        'allowed_types'   => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|doc|xml",
        'overwrite'       => TRUE,          
    );
    get_instance()->load->library('upload', $this->config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload())          
    {
        echo "file upload success";             
    }           
    else            
    {
        echo $this->upload->display_errors();           
    }       
}
```

Comment: i have another error with "The upload path does not appear to be valid."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in codeigniter  the default file name that will be uploaded is **userfile**, if you are going to upload file with another name you need to pass it to do_upload method

```
function save_blog(){ 
    $config = array( 'upload_path' => 'server_path',
                     'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|doc|xml",
                     'overwrite' => TRUE, );

    get_instance()->load->library('upload', $this->config); 
    if($this->upload->do_upload('myDoc')) { 
        echo "file upload success"; 
    } else { 
        echo $this->upload->display_errors(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: May i as k another question, when i use $this->upload->do_upload('myDoc') i have error with "The upload path does not appear to be valid.". in my 'server_path' i used 'ftp://username:password@hostname:port/public_html/img/blog/' that ther are this path on my server

Comment: the first time is see that there is ability to authenticate connection to server via your method 'username:password@host:port',
Unless you want to upload via ftp  you can use  ftp class "http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/ftp.html"

You can use the directory path directly without username, password & host by using absolute or relative path for writable directory.

Answer (score 0):

do_upload expects a form field called "userfile", which is not your case. To set another field name, you have to pass it as a parameter:

```
$field_name = "some_field_name";
$this->upload->do_upload($field_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" name = "myDoc" id = "myDoc" accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf,.txt,.xls,.xlsx,.ppt,.pptx">
```

use your input type='file' name (myDoc) as

`$this->upload->do_upload("myDoc")`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $this->upload->display_errors();
```

You have error in MVC Technique
You CAN'T "echo" anything in controller